# How to use layoutDirection to mirror the whole layout dynamically in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to build a frontend view of an android application. I have to dynamically push the whole display to the right of the screen.

I want to push the whole relative layout to the right of my screen.

Following is my XML code:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/message_single_layout"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity=""
        android:weightSum="10">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/message_profile_layout"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:src="@drawable/default_avatar" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/message_text_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name_text_layout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/message_profile_layout"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/their_message"
            android:text="Message Text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_text_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/message_profile_layout"
            android:text="Display Name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_text_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/message_text_layout"
            android:layout_marginStart="-15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/name_text_layout"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/message_image_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/message_text_layout"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/message_text_layout"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/message_profile_layout"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to do it dynamically.
I have tried changing `gravity` to `right`, `layout_gravity` to `right`. `SetGravity()` function. Nothing is solving my problem.
Please help me.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an **RelativeLayout** object in your Activity or fragment as field

```
private RelativeLayout mRoot;
```

Initialize your root layout object variable as below :

**In Activity:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);

         mRoot= findViewById(R.id.message_single_layout);
    }
```

**in Fragment:**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mRoot= (RelativeLayout) view;
}
```

And where ever you want set your root **layout Direction** to rtl (if your minimum SKD is at least 17). rtl means Right to left

```
    mRoot.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

I hope this will help you !!

Comment: gravity doesn't work with relative layout what is got to know from someone

Comment: try to set layout_direction to rtl in layout or dinamically